# React - can you pass state handler down multiple child component layers

Tags: reactjs

I have a React parent component that holds state for the whole app. I want to pass a function down to a child component to so that when a button is clicked in that child then it changes the parent's state.  Now I can do this for one layer, however when I've tried to pass the function down to a further layer (so a child component passing down a function it received as a prop) my app falls over with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

Is it possible to pass this function down through multiple layers?

In my lowest level I don't have constructor set up as I thought that was only needed it I needed to initiate state in the child component, is that right?

I've detailed below the relevant parts of my code:

Parent:

```
  class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.changeDisplay = this.changeDisplay.bind(this)
    this.handleAddTicket = this.handleAddTicket.bind(this)
    this.handleDeleteTicket = this.handleDeleteTicket.bind(this)

    this.state = {...}
...
}

 handleDeleteTicket(data){
    console.log(data)

  } ....
```

First Child

```
class Board extends React.Component {
return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <Todo tasks={todoTasks} deleteTicket={this.props.deleteTicket}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
  )
}
```

Second Child:

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
render() {
todoTicketsAr = this.props.tasks.map(function (obj, i) {
                return <Ticket key={i} data={obj} deleteTicket={this.props.deleteTicket}></Ticket>
            })
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>To do:</h2>
                {todoTicketsAr}
            </div>
                )
    }
```

So I'm binding this at the parent level but nowhere else, is that right?

Comment: It should be possible. Can you post your code?

Comment: Yes it's possible, it's called "prop drilling". React's new Context API should help you too, it does what you're doing but allows you to skip all the intermediate components. For your specific issue you'd have to post the relevant code, kind of hard to say based on the info given.

Comment: Thank you both, I've put some snippets of my code in the edit, hopefully that has enough to decipher whats going on.

Comment: @Steve examples on how to fix you problems have been provided below

Comment: great, thank you, i'll give them a go!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how to do it with prop drilling and context API. I would use the Context API example because you don't need to keep prop drilling when you need to use different parts of the state within different components.

I have also provided a prop drilling example if you want to see that working and compare the two solutions.

### React Context API Example

```js
const Global = React.createContext({});

class Store extends React.Component {
  static Consumer = Global.Consumer;
  state = {
    value: 'bacon',
  };
  changeValue = (value) => this.setState({ value });
  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    const { changeValue } = this;
    return (
      <Global.Provider value={{
        value,
        changeValue,
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Global.Provider>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: '',
  };
  handleChange = (evt) => this.setState({ text: evt.target.value });
  render() {
    const { text } = this.state;
    const { handleChange } = this;
    return (
      <Store.Consumer>
        {({ value, changeValue }) => (
          <div>
            <h3>Value is {value}</h3>
            <h5>Type a new value and submit</h5>
            <input value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
            <button onClick={() => changeValue(text)}>Submit</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </Store.Consumer>
    )
  }
}

const Layout = () => (
  <div>
    <h5>An example component that is not exposed to context</h5>
    <Child/>
  </div>
)

const Main = () => (
  <Store>
    <h2>React Context API example</h2>
    <Layout/>
  </Store>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.body);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

### Prop drilling example

```js
const ChildOfChild = ({ toggleDisplay }) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={toggleDisplay}>Toggle in Child of Child</button>
  </div>
);

const Child = ({ toggleDisplay }) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={toggleDisplay}>Toggle in Child</button>
    <ChildOfChild toggleDisplay={toggleDisplay} />
  </div>
);

class Main extends React.Component {
  state = {
    display: true,
  };
  toggleDisplay = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      display: !prevState.display,
    }));
  };
  render() {
    const { toggleDisplay } = this;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>React Prop drilling Example</h2>
        <pre>{this.state.display.toString()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.toggleDisplay}>Parent</button>
        <Child toggleDisplay={toggleDisplay} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main/>,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time that would happen is because `this` is no longer bound correctly. One common situation I could give is:

The will throw an error

```
class App extends Component {
     someClickHandler() {
         /** 
          * This line will throw an error onClick 
          * of the button because `this` is not bound to the right thing.
          * If you log out `this` you'll probably see the click event object. 
          */
         console.log(this.state); 
     }
     render() {
          return (
              <button onClick={this.someHandler}>Random button</button
          )
     }
}
```

To properly bind `this` you have to do either

```
<button onClick={() => this.someHandler()}>Random button</button>

// or

<button onClick={this.someHandler.bind(this)}>Random button</button>
```